# How to avoid <div> elements being displaced when one is expanded

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am building a calendar using `<div>` elements and CSS.

Using jQuery, when a day on the calendar is clicked, a class is applied to the `<div>` element. This causes the day to expand.

**The Problem:**

When the day expands, it displaces all of the other divs in the calendar. Seen in the images below.

**HTML**

The HTML is created by a PHP for loop, displaying every day in the selected month.

```
<div id="calender">
     <div id="cal-day" class="1" onclick="expand(1)">
         <div id="datenum"><p>1</p></div>
     </div>
     <div id="cal-day" class="2" onclick="expand(2)">
         <div id="datenum"><p>2</p></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

**CSS** - I have removed the aesthetic styling code for readibility.

```
#calender{
    position: relative;
    width: 1230px;
    height: 800px;
}

#cal-day{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#datenum{
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
.dayselected{

    overflow: scroll !important;
    width: 400px !important;
    height: 400px !important;

}
#content{
    display: none;
}
#content.show{
    display: block;
}
```

jQuery:

```
function expand(date){

     if($("." + date).hasClass("dayselected")){

        $("." + date).removeClass("dayselected");
        $(".content" + date).removeClass("show");

     }else{

        $("." + selectedDay).removeClass("dayselected");
        $("." + date).addClass("dayselected");
        $(".content" + date).addClass("show");

    }

    selectedDay = date;

 }
```

Before is day is selected:

[image: Before a day is selected:]

After a day is selected, with the other `<div>` elements displaced:

[image: After a day is selected:]

Would it be possible to have the day clicked overlay the other divs instead of displacing them?

Here is a JSFiddle:   https://jsfiddle.net/quucxwpy/

Comment: FYI your HTML is invalid as you have numerous duplicate `id` attributes. They should be unique within a document. If you need to group elements, use classes. Also, could you setup a working example in http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: try display:inline-block inside show class instead display:block. If you create jsfiddle for this issue. we can help you better.

Comment: Have you thought about copying the contents of the selected day div to a new div which is positioned absolutely?

Comment: im creating a jsfiddle now

Comment: why .dayselected class has height and width as 400px each whereas #cal-day is with 200px. I think if you change .dayselected to 200px each it should work.

Comment: @SachinKadam the whole point is that it's a larger view of the selected date...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly you have several duplicated `id` attributes, which means your HTML is invalid. These should be changed to classes.

To solve the issue, one possible solution to this would be to `clone()` the original `cal-day` element and position it absolutely over the original. This would then not break the document flow of the other sibling `cal-day` elements. Try this:

```
<div id="calender">
    <div class="cal-day">
        <div class="datenum">
            <p>1</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cal-day">
        <div class="datenum">
            <p>2</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- other days...
</div>
```

```js
$('.cal-day').click(function() {
    $('#dayselected').remove();
    var $day = $(this);
    var $dayClone = $day.clone(false)
        .prop('id', 'dayselected')
        .css({
            top: $day.position().top,
            left: $day.position().left
        })
        .appendTo('#calender');
});

$('#calender').on('click', '#dayselected', function() {
    $(this).remove();
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6qh95y3a/)

Comment: This is great, but is there no way of doing it by just adding and removing a class?

Comment: No, as the fix is to use `position: absolute` to stop the other sibling elements being affected when one is expanded. The alternative is to make them *all* absolutely positioned, but this means that you would need to set `top` and `left` individually on them all in CSS, which is not a good idea for lots of reasons.

Comment: plus 1 for introducing me to `clone()`.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Comment: yes. This is working for me also. Thanks  @Rory McCrossan